# Apache Kafka: do a producer sees the whole network, or only the brokers of the topics it is interested in?

Tags: apache-kafka

When a producer wants to write a record to a partition, the producer talks directly with the broker leader of such partition, but since such leader might not be one of the choosen bootstrap servers, I'm interested to know the dynamics of such network exchanges.

Two approaches:

- At instantiation time of the producer (and not at the first call to `send`), the producer tries to connect to one of the bootstrap servers to receive all topics, brokers, partitions, etc, cache the results, and then use that cache metadata to know to which broker to talk to at any point in the future (and reload whenever the cache expires).
- By default, the producer never knows the whole list of brokers/partitions/topics etc, only the brokers related to the topics it has ever sent at least one record to. So at the first call to `send` to a topic the producer has never seen so far, it talks to one of the brokers he already knows (be it a bootstrap server, or to any other broker that it already knows it's responsive from recent past activity), gets the metadata for that topic only, and afterwards talk to the partition leader the producer is interested in.

Regarding the first approach, based on other answers from this site, it doesn't look like that's the case, but I still don't understand the whole picture of the second approach.

The second approach, which I guess is the actual one (the producer never sees the whole network), implies among other things that the metadata is stored in the producer topic-wise, so that each topic metadata has its own cache expiration time and so on.

But this second approach opens a new question, what happens if the producer sends a message to a topic, but never sends a second message to the same topic again? Will the producer refresh that metadata at expiration anyway, or only when a new `send` requests is issued?